# How to take periodic screenshots from Windows 7 in background for upload or email

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, remote-access, desktop, teamviewer

My org manages a fleet of ~150 kiosks. We have Teamviewer installed on every machine. They are all separate installations, geographically dispersed around the country.The kiosks are all running windows 7 with a touch screen. They are supposed to have a Google Chrome full screen in kiosk mode, to allow the user to interact with the kiosk (and prevent access to the desktop). They are programmed to open Chrome on reboot.

The problem arises when the kiosk reboots and the internet is disconnected. Our website is not displayed, and a user can click the `Running Network Diagnostics` button in chrome as seen in the image. Once they click that the tool bar opens up and they click around to escape the kiosk mode.

[Chrome No Internet Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZ8fZ.png)

What I am interested in is some sort of automated solution that can upload the screen captures of the desktop periodically to a remote server. That way, I can then view the last desktop screen of every PC.

If they aren't connected to the internet I can tell that via TeamViewer, but if they aren't in kiosk mode I have no visibility. TeamVeiwer doesn't provide any sort of solution for this. I would be open to a 3rd party management solution to preview the desktops for my ~150 TeamViewer connections.

Currently the only way for me to check is to manually open up a TeamViewer session on each of my kiosks one at a time to see what the screen is displaying. I am also interested in other solutions for how to force kiosk mode, but that is for another question. I searched around and there are many windows programs that take screenshots, but nothing that offers exactly what I am looking for.

**tldr**: I am looking for a solution to automatically upload a desktop screenshot to a remote server (or some other way to see the desktop without manually connecting). I am open to any solutions : paid, software, scripts etc.

Comment: Doesn't Windows 7 have an "assigned access" kiosk mode built-in, to lock everything down to one app?

Answer (score 1):

You can [take screenshots in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2970339/2879900), and then you can store them where you want or send them by e-mail with [Send-MailMessage](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-6).

Schedule the script with the Task Scheduler (the task should run in the user context).